# Compose, MVI и MutableState: как внутри ВьюМодели триггерить новое обращение к БД, не создавая лишних сущностей?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlinx-coroutines, mvi

я тяну данные из БД при попощи `flow`, которые дергает новые данные при изменении в одном из 2-х триггеров
`(seqrchQuery: String, categoriesToDisplay: List<Category>)`. С фрагментами это выглядит так (во вьюМодели):

```
init {  
    combine(
        searchQuery, // StateFlow
        categoriesToDisplay // StateFlow
    ) { query, categories ->
        Pair(query, categories)
    }.flatMapLatest { (q, c) ->
        vocabularyUseCases.observeWordsBySearchQueryInCategories(q, c)
    }.onEach {
        //todo handle the result
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Сейчас я использую Compose и храню состояние в `var state by mutableStateOf(MyState())`,
причем `MyState` уже содержит поля `searchQuery` и `categoriesToDisplay`.

Нужно ли создавать отдельные флоу для этих двух триггеров, или я могу как-то отслеживать их значение
прям в этом `state`, и дергать при их изменении БД?

Не хотелось бы дублировать одни и те же данные в отдельные флоу.

Есть ли какой-то best practice для таких триггеров при использовании Compose и единого `state`?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Все варианты нормальные. Вы можете использовать просто snapshotFlow(state) или же  searchQuery+categoriesToDisplay без MyState. А если нужно MyState, но к нему не подписаться, то нормально создать дополнительные точки подписки, что вы и сделали